# Пропал пункт "Редакции" в боковом меню WordPress

Tags: wordpress

в какой-то момент времени исчез пункт "Редакции" при редактировании записи в разделе Записи. (Запись точно имеет редакции). Но при этом, при редактировании записей в разделе Страницы он есть. Куда копать?

Comment: Эта ссылка появляется когда у записи есть редакции. Соответственно в записях не имеющих редакций его нет.

Comment: редакции  точно есть, вносил правки. Дело в том, что для новых записей все нормально, для очень старых - нормально. Но есть часть, у которой ревизии не отображаются. Все посты стандартные, меняются только тэги. Пока не смог понять причин.

Comment: В них нет редакций. Убедиться в этом можно загляну в базу данных.